# MQTT WebSocket Connection Failed

Tags: websocket, mqtt

I am new to programming and having a roadblock.
I am doing a DRTLS project and having issues with it.
Whenever I run my code and view in Console of my Chrome browser I keep getting
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.0.156:1883/' failed:".
Any pros could help out?

[image: MQTT.fx Connection Profiles]

[image: WebSocket Connection Failed]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.4.0.min.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.4.0.min.js"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-2.4.0.min.js"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-gl-2.4.0.min.js"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-mathjax-2.4.0.min.js"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Bokeh.set_log_level("info");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map0"></div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/mqtt/dist/mqtt.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    if(window.screen.width > 600){
        var width = window.screen.width/2 - 40
    }else{
        var width = window.screen.width
    }
    var height = 700;
    var i = 0;
    async function fetch_plot(){
        const response = await fetch('/api-Map-w='+width+'&h='+height);
        var item = await response.json();
        Bokeh.embed.embed_item(item, "map0");
    }
    async function fetch_path(count, startPoint, endPoint){
        document.getElementById("map" + count).remove();
        var elemDiv = document.createElement('div');
        count = count + 1;
        elemDiv.id = "map" + count;
        document.body.appendChild(elemDiv);
        const response = await fetch('/api-Path-s='+startPoint+'&e='+endPoint);
        var newItem = await response.json();
        Bokeh.embed.embed_item(newItem, "map" + i);
    }
    fetch_plot();
    // var options = {
    // mqtt_user: "dwmuser",
    // mqtt_password: "dwmpass",
    //     will: {
    //         mqtt_topic_prefix: 'dwm',
    //     }
    // }
    const client = mqtt.connect("ws://192.168.0.156:1883", { clientId: "ee9ea05d56814fd9992bf1ef34119683", username: "dwmuser", password: "dwmpass" });

    // var client = mqtt.connect('ws://192.168.0.156:1883', options=options);
    // console.log(client);
    
    // function insertpoint(name, x, y) {
    //     var ds = Bokeh.documents[0].get_model_by_name(name)
    //     var len = ds.data.x.push(x)
    //     ds.data.y.push(y)
    //     if(len > 5){
    //         ds.data.x.shift()
    //         ds.data.y.shift()
    //     }
    //     ds.change.emit()
    // }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as it turned out, WebSocket uses a different port from MQTT. This can be checked under mosquitto.conf file. For those who're going to come to this thread looking for the port number for WebSocket, it is 15675 by default.

Answer (score 3):

For nearly all MQTT brokers (including mosquitto) you need to configure separate listeners for native MQTT and MQTT over WebSockets.

The default port for native MQTT is 1883, you will not be able to connect to this port using the Paho JavaScript MQTT client library from the browser.

You will need to make sure that your broker is correctly configured with a MQTT over WebSockets listener, then make sure you use the connect port in the web page when connecting.

MQTTfx in the screen shot is connecting to native MQTT.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help and prompt reply. For MQTT.fx I am able to subscribe and retrieve all the data. But when I do it on my own code, I get the WebSocket Connection as mentioned. Am new to these, able to explain in simpler terms :)

Comment: As I said, you need to configure mosquitto to add a listener that supports MQTT over WebSockets, the man page for `mosquitto.conf` includes all the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

this config worked for me

```
const URL = "ws://x.xxx.xx.xxx:8000";

  mqtt.connect(URL, {
      connectTimeout: 5000,
      hostname: "x.xxx.xx.xxx",
      port: 8000,
      path: "/mqtt",
    });
```